# Testing one test function using another, after testing that one?

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing, phpunit, php-5.5

I have some test classes and functions that I'm writing in PHP, and I had a question about standards when it comes to coding them.

I have a function that creates a back-end storage object, stores it in a database, retrieves it and then asserts that the values in the DB are identical to the ones it inputted.

I also have another function that *modifies* the above back-end object, but to do that it needs to exist, of course. Would it be prudent to have the second function call the first one (which also returns the data that was created after verifying it is correct) so that I can automate the modification test without hard-coding everything? If not, are there alternatives to this approach besides hard-coding values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PHPUnit you can make a test dependant on another, by using the @depends annotation. You can also pass values from the first test to the dependant one.
The second test will not be executed if the first one fails. And you can make a third test depedant on the second, or more than one test dependant o another (for example to test the deletion, you dont need the update to work, just the insertion).

```
 public function testCreateRegister()
 {
     $db = new Database();
     $register_id = $db->createRegister('hello');

     // ...
     // check that the register was inserted correctly
     // ...

     return $register_id;
 }

 /**
  * @depends testCreateRegister
  */
 public function testUpdateRegister($register_id)
 {
     $db = new Database();
     $this->assertTrue($db->updateRegister('hi');
 }
```

As explained in the docs:

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/writing-tests-for-phpunit.html#writing-tests-for-phpunit.test-dependencies

Comment: Ah, I see. Is it also the case here that `testCreateRegister` is a data provider for `testUpdateRegister`? Ie., does PHPUnit automatically pass the return values of `testCreateRegister` to `testUpdateRegister` in the order that they are given?

Comment: No. They work differently. You can only pass one value between dependant tests (it can be an array though). But it's not the same as Dataproviders, as the dependant test will be executed just once.

Comment: Great, that's exactly what I needed. I'll be accepting your answer, thanks!